# Orchard CMS Default Rss feeds for blog

Tags: rss, orchardcms

I'm Trying to display a RSS link to a blog post in `Orchard 1.5` (should be simple right)

I feel I must be missing something here :

The documentation [here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Rss-atom) seems out of date? I can't find any instance of the `Html.RegisterFeed` or `Html.FeedLink` in my current `Orchard 1.5.1` codebase.

I can see the `<link />` tags have been inserted into the `Header` section of the page.

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="News" href="/Riders/rss?containerid=85" shape-id="334">
```

And I'm looking at the View in `Orchard.Core/Feeds/Views/Feeds.cshtml` and I can see

```
@Model.FeedManager.GetRegisteredLinks(Html)
```

But I don't know how to get this to render on my page, ideally in First aside section.

Could someone point me in the right direction.

**For instance**

I want to put something like

```
<a href="@Html.MyFeedUrl" class="rss">RSS feed</a>
```

and it would render

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean: the blog module already has RSS.

Comment: I believe he wants to put a link to the RSS feed on the `AsideFirst` zone of the page

Comment: How do I show the link to the rss feed/s in a custom view ?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy, how is the RSS enabled in the blog module?

Comment: What do you mean enabled? It just comes with the blog module.

Comment: i got it, containerid=12 showed the entries. where can i find containerid in the db?

Comment: In the admin go to blogs > select the blog > look at the url, should say Admin/Blogs/86 86 is my containerid